# SELECT COUNT of MAX from GROUP BY with multiple HAVING clauses (I think)

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, max, having

My table:

```
  id    user    area    login         colour
  ------------------------------------------
  1     2       7      2014-01-05     red
  2     1       7      2014-01-03     green
  3     3       7      2014-01-08     red
  4     2       7      2014-01-22     green
  5     3       7      2014-01-15     amber
  6     1       7      2014-01-12     green
  7     3       7      2014-01-23     red
  8     4       7      2014-01-05     red
  9     3       7      2014-01-12     green
 10     4       7      2014-01-28     amber
 11     1       4      2014-01-06     amber
```

from a list of ONLY each users LAST login (ie MAX(login))
I need a count of those logins from area 7 with the colour green

From the given table, ids 4, 6 and 9 have the latest login date for area 7 and colour green so I would want my query to return their count which is 3.

scratchy head time.

Comment: Is this for SQL_Server?

Comment: Doesn't user 2 also meet your criteria?

Comment: The lastest login for `user=3` is `2014-01-23` and is `red`. Why should this count?

Comment: Yes it's for ms sql server, user 2 does meet the criteria and is why row with id 4 is included in the results and my mistake, please amend row 7 so the login date is in the late renaissance. 

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's for SQL-Server, you can use windows aggregate functions:

```
; WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT login, area, colour, 
           maxlogin = MAX(login) OVER (PARTITION BY [user]) 
    FROM dbo.logins
  )
SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte
WHERE maxlogin = login
  AND area = 7
  AND colour = 'green' ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c503/16)**

Comment: Awesome. I see how this works, unfortunately when I ran it on the example data (with the row 7 date set to 1664) I received a count of only 2.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: 1664? Is that a date?

Comment: I apologise for my flippancy. It is a year from the late renaissance to be applied to row 7 in answer to your initial question (2013 would do just as well).
This then would leave the rows with the latest login date, in area 7 with the colour green as 4,6 and 9 - a total of 3.

Comment: It's just been pointed out to me, row 5 should be 2013 too. No wonder no on has been able to answer this.

Simply put: Get the latest login for all users and return the count of those that are area 7 and colour green.

Comment: Confused. Does my query answer your problem or not? It does what your specifications say.

Comment: Ypercube, Yes, I've rerun your query on lots of different data and it does the trick quite nicely. Sorry again for the confusion and thanks for the fix.

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure if this is what you wanted. If you move the `area = 7` condition inside the cte, you'll get different result (only logins from area 7 will be considered.)

Comment: Cool. Now all I have to do is remember what I was going to use this for.